# ionic - how can I set up DocumentViewer to show up in ion-content

Tags: ionic-framework, documentviewer

I am new to Ionic and Angular. I have set up my ionic correctly, have created my app "myApp" and have installed the DocumentViewer plugin I want to use. I have even imported it in my app.module.ts and app.component.ts by this code:

```
import { DocumentViewer} from '@ionic-native/document-viewer'
```

It is even loaded in Providers Array:

```
  providers: [
    DocumentViewer,
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
```

The apps.component.ts codes:

```
  constructor(public document: DocumentViewer, platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
      this.document.viewDocument('../assets/Mary.pdf', 'application/pdf');
    });
  }
```

The problem is how can I display the file in my details page I created? I have googled around but no relevant answer that did help me. I would appreciate your help.

My details.html page:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>{{item.text}}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
  <h2>Welcome #{{item.id}}</h2>
  <p>
    Great job!

  </p>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Hi there, I'm going through the same issue. Have you got the solution for this issue?

Comment: same here, no relevant solution, same wrong documentation

Comment: Not yet, don't know why anybody can answer